# checkBox query In TableView in iPhone

Tags: ios, uitableview, checkbox

I've created checkBox in my `tableView` and working properly but when I'm going to previous view and coming back to checkBox view,the checkBox which i have checked are not remained checked. so what to do? I used two images to create checkBox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state of checkbox is not stored on images. Rather it is shown through some model/data source.

If you have a number of checkboxes, store the states in an array, and update the array values based on you check or uncheck.

And you can make this array shared.global or static to that class, so that it is initialized just one. In your case if will be initialized every time you load your view.

Comment: I've only one Imageview but  i assigned tag to that imgview cellForRowAtIndexPath  and in didSelectRow im using that tag value to change the state of the cheakBox.when it's checked,I'm storing the value of that particular row in array(contact_NO in my case) and when it's uncheaked i im removing the valuefrom array...